# Xamarin OpenInputStream permission ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMEN

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, permission-denied

I'm developing an app on android and i'm getting an exception when i use openInputStream with certain uri, here is my code

```
try
{
   using (var stream = Context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uriString)))
   {
      //
   }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

when the uri = 'content://media/external/images/media/61155' I get no exception

but when the uri is like this 'content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A61797'

I get this exception

> Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord.... requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

I have no idea how to resolve this

I'm testing with a device with android oreo 8.0

Minimum android sdk api 21 (Lollipop 5.0)

Target android sdk api 24 (Nougat 7.0)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are performing a document open Intent, you need to request the uri permission(s) (read and/or write) that you need via `TakePersistableUriPermission`

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == (int)ResultCode.Chooser && resultCode.HasFlag(Result.Ok))
    {
        var uri = data.Data;
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {
            ContentResolver.TakePersistableUriPermission(uri, ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        }
        using (var stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri))
        {          
            Log.Debug("TAG", uri.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

re: [takePersistableUriPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)ContentResolver.TakePersistableUriPermission)

Comment: I'm not trying to open stream inside of onactivityresult, the uristring is stored in a sqlite database, when I call my method the exception happends, I dont have access to the original uri of the onactivityresult method

Comment: @user3525706 It is still relevant to use TakePersistableUriPermission. Be aware that content provider uris are volitile and long term persistent is not advised. You should request the perm when you first get the uri, and re-request it before using the uri later on

Comment: I Will try it tomorrow

Comment: I getting an error in this line of code  Context.ContentResolver.TakePersistableUriPermission(uri, ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission); Java.Lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10171 and Uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:62224 [user 0]