# Xamarin Android cannot re-access shared files

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, permissions

**TL;DR...**

How do I re-access files which have been shared to my Xamarin Android app, which worked on first sharing, but I get permission exceptions when I try and access them again later on?

---

I'm writing my first Xamarin Android (**not Forms**) app, which I want to be able to "share" photos well as "add" photos.

By "share" I mean you open Gallery, select one or more photos, and share them to my app via `Intent.ActionSend` and `Intent.ActionSendMultiple`.

And by "add" I mean you click on a button within the app, which allows you to add a photo via the `Intent.ActionOpenDocument`.

I've been able to set "Persistable Permissions" on images that I have added via the `ActionOpenDocument` using the following (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866276/930393))...

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if ((requestCode == c_addPhoto) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
    {
        Uri uri = data.Data;
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            ContentResolver.TakePersistableUriPermission(uri, ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        AddToList(uri);
    }
}
```

This works, and when I re-open the application the images are accessed using Uri values such as...

```
 content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A2122
```

---

**My issue** is being able to access images that have been shared via the `Intent.ActionSend` and `Intent.ActionSendMultiple` where the Uri that is passed through the `Intent.ClipData.Item` is in the following format...

```
 content://media/external/images/media/1998
```

If I try and run the `TakePersistableUriPermission` on the Uri after it is passed to my app, I get the following exception...

> Java.Lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10254 and Uri content://media/external/images/media/1998 [user 0]

And if I try and access the Uri I get the following exception...

> Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/1998 from pid=4042, uid=10254 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

But I **do** have the following in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

- How do I grant the file permission for access in the future?
- Or do I need to translate the Uri from the `content://media...` to `content://com.android...` format, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the File/Content Provider implementation in your Android solution?
This is one that I answered for Xamarin Forms app though it should be same for Xamarin Android since everything you need to do for File Provider you will do in Android platform specific project:
[File Download in Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151409/file-download-in-xamarin-forms/52172875#52172875)

Android defined the File/Content Provider since Api version 22 which means if your app runs on or above that versions you must define the File Provider for your app to be able to Share the files.

Here's the official page https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Comment: Many thanks - I don't have time to go back to this at the moment (it's a personal project) but I'll let you know when I give it a go